# Mapping a select input with a Scalaform in Play 2.5 - using a DTO object

Tags: scala, playframework

I have the following controller in Play2.5 taken from github repo raul782/play-commerce.

```
class CategoryController(implicit inj: Injector) extends Controller {

  private val categoryService = inject[CategoryService]

  def viewAllCategories = Action { implicit request =>
    val allCategories = categoryService.findAll.map(Category.toDTO(_))
    Ok(views.html.product.categoryList(allCategories))
  }

  def listCategories = Action { implicit request =>
    val allCategories = categoryService.findAll.map(Category.toDTO(_))
    Ok(RequestUtil.toJsonString(allCategories)).as(JSON)
  }

  def viewCategoryForm(categoryId: Long) = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.product.category(views.forms.product.categoryForm,      categoryService.findAll))
  }

  def addCategoryForm = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.product.category(views.forms.product.categoryForm,   categoryService.findAll))
  }

  def addCategory = Action { implicit request =>
    import views.forms.product.categoryForm
    categoryForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => {
        Ok(views.html.product.category(formWithErrors, categoryService.findAll))
    },
      categoryDTO => {
        play.Logger.debug(request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.toString)
        play.Logger.debug(categoryDTO.toString)
        val category = Category.fromDTO(categoryDTO)
        categoryService.save(category)

        Redirect(routes.CategoryController.viewAllCategories())
      }
    )
  }
}
```

I have my category.html.scala setup as:

```
@(categoryForm: Form[dtos.product.CategoryDTO], categoryDTOs:     Seq[models.product.Category])(implicit request:     play.api.mvc.Request[play.api.mvc.AnyContent])

@import models.product.Category
@import helper._
@import views.html.forms.inputHidden
@import views.forms.FormHelpers.bootstrapVerticalFormFieldConstructor

@title = @{categoryForm(Category.Id).value.
                    map(_ => Messages("forms.categories.update")).
                    getOrElse(Messages("forms.categories.add"))}

@action = @{categoryForm(Category.Id).value.
                    map(_ =>     controllers.product.routes.CategoryController.updateCategory()).
                        getOrElse(controllers.product.routes.CategoryController.addCategory())}

@categoryOptions = @{categoryDTOs.map(category => category.id.toString -> category.name)}

@main(title = title) {
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <h2>@title</h2>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-7">
    @form(action = action, args = 'class -> "well") {
        @inputHidden(categoryForm(Category.Id))
        @inputText(categoryForm(Category.Name), 'class -> "form-control")
        @select(categoryForm(Category.ParentCategory), categoryOptions,      'class -> "form-control", '_default -> "--- select ---")
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">               
                @Messages("forms.save")
            </button>
            <a href="@controllers.product.routes.CategoryController.viewAllCategories()" class="btn btn-default">@Messages("forms.cancel")</a>
        </div>
    }
</div>
}
```

My form mapping is built as follows:

```
package views.forms

import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import dtos.product.CategoryDTO

package object product {
  val categoryForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "id" -> optional(longNumber(strict = true)),
      "name" -> text(minLength = 1, maxLength = 255),
      "parentCategoryId" -> list(optional(longNumber))
    ) (CategoryDTO.apply) (CategoryDTO.unapply)
  )
}
```

My CategoryDTO class is as follows:

```
package dtos.product

case class CategoryDTO(id: Option[Long], name: String, parentCategoryId: List[Option[Long]]) {
  var ancestry: Seq[CategoryDTO] = Nil
  var parentCategoryName: Option[String] = None
}
```

My Category model is as follows:

```
package models.product

import models.BaseEntity
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.Access
import javax.persistence.AccessType
import java.util.LinkedHashSet
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne
import javax.persistence.OneToMany
import java.util.{Set => JSet}
import models.IdentifierProperty
import dtos.product.CategoryDTO

@Entity
class Category extends BaseEntity {

  def this(id: Option[Long]) = {
   this()
   this.id = id
  }

  @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
  var name: String = _

  @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = classOf[Category])
  var parentCategory: Option[Category] = None

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCategory")
  var childCategories: JSet[Category] = new LinkedHashSet

  def ancestors = {
    traverseAncestry(parentCategory)  
  }

  private def traverseAncestry(parentCategory: Option[Category], lst: List[Category] = Nil): Seq[Category] = {
    parentCategory  match {
      case Some(currentParentCategory) => traverseAncestry(currentParentCategory.parentCategory, currentParentCategory :: lst)
      case _ => lst
    }
  }

  protected def getParentCategory() = {
    parentCategory.getOrElse(null)
  }

  protected def setParentCategory(category: Category) {
    parentCategory = Option(category)
  }
}

object Category extends IdentifierProperty {
  val Name = "name"
  val ParentCategory = "parentCategoryId"
  val ChildCategories = "childCategories"

  def toDTO(category: Category, withAncestry: Boolean = false): CategoryDTO =   {
    val dto = CategoryDTO(category.id, category.name, category.parentCategory.map( c => c.id).toList)
    dto.parentCategoryName = category.parentCategory.map(_.name)
    dto.ancestry = if(withAncestry) { 
      category.ancestors.map(Category.toDTO(_)) 
    } else { 
      Nil
    }
    dto
  }

  def fromDTO(dto: CategoryDTO) = {
    val category = new Category
    category.name = dto.name
    category.parentCategory = dto.parentCategoryId match {
      case Nil => None
      case head::_ => head.map(id => new Category(Some(id)))
    }
    category
  }
}
```

When I fill the form and submit the request, the form is saved but only the name, but not the parentCategory.
I've noticed that the select input value sent is Some(15) where 15 is the parentCategoryId.

Initially the categoryForm mapping for parentCategoryId was just optional(longNumber), but I couldn't capture the value either.

I switched to list(optional(longNumber)) because that's what it looks the docs say when you use a select input.

But still no luck, any advice or what could be wrong with my implementation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your question and the fact that a category only has a single parent category name, I'm assuming you want just the (single) id of the parent category? This is quite a typical "foreign key" situation. The `select` element only selects (by default) a single element.

- In the mapping, use an `optional(longNumber)` rather than a list.
- In the dto make it an `Option[Int]` rather than a collection.

If you're after a list of parent categories, then your current code is closer to what you'll need but select on its own won't do it - you will need a multiselect javascript library.

P.S. Any reason you're using var not val?